# nodejs hash string to integer array fixed length 2

Tags: node.js, hash

i am trying to create a method to generate **two** **Intergers** from a String [a-z] 
with max length of 10 chars in **Nodejs**,
for ex:

```
var arr=hashfn("subdomain");
```

the "`arr`" be like `[55,111]` , this is an idea to creates automatically an node server app with two ports *(http,https)* ,

i am trying to use MD5 hash (32 chars) , and substring the 4 first chars as arr[0] and the 4 chars as arr[1] , but i dont know if this method is **good** !

Answer (score 0):

i think i found the solution ,using djb2 hash algorithm ,

- using SHA1 instead MD5
- take the first 3 chars and the 3 next chars

source: http://www.cse.yorku.ca/~oz/hash.html

```
function hashfn(s) {
            var xhash = 0,c=0,i=0;
             while (c = s[i++])
                xhash = ((xhash << 5) + xhash) + c.charCodeAt(0) -48; // 48 is the 0 (ascii)
            return xhash;
}

var subdomain="www";
var arr={};

shasum.update(subdomain);
var hash=shasum.digest('hex');

arr.httpchars=hash.substr(0,3);
arr.httpschars=hash.substr(3,3);


arr.httpport=hashfn(arr.httpchars);
arr.httpsport=hashfn(arr.httpschars);


console.log(hash,arr);
```

**console:**

[image]

thanks.